# Unclosed Character Character Literal Error

Tags: java

My code is below.  Not sure how to eliminate this problem.  I tried using `next.Line()`, but that did not work.

```
String demoEmpName;
int demoIdNum;
double demoPayRate;
int demoHoursWorked;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("What is your name?");
demoEmpName = keyboard.nextString();

System.out.println("What is your ID number?");
demoIdNum = keyboard.nextInt(); 

System.out.println("What is your hourly pay rate?");
demoPayRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

System.out.println("How many hours did you work?");
demoHoursWorked = keyboard.nextInt();

Payroll pyrll = new Payroll(demoEmpName, demoIdNum, demoPayRate, demoHoursWorked);
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the error you're receiving, preferably the exact message?

Comment: above code seems ok. Are there any other code apart from this?

Comment: I never heard about `nextString`.

Comment: There is no "Unclosed Character Character Literal Error" in this code.  If you want people to help you, you need to provide a *clear* description of the problem and an *accurate* copy of *relevant* error messages.

Comment: And if that is all of your code, you need to go back to your lecture notes or whatever ... because that looks *nothing* like a valid Java class.

Answer (score 2):

Change `keyboard.nextString()` to `keyboard.next()`.

There is no `nextString()` method in [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

Oh, and in case all this code you posted is not enclosed in some method, that would be another problem.

Comment: That doesnt makes sense with the error that OP mentioned.

Comment: @almasshaikh Well, I tried that code (except of calling the `Payroll` constructor), and that's the only error I got.

Comment: are you sure? I would have assumed it should have given something like method ... not defined in scanner class?

Comment: @almasshaikh I didn't get the same error posted by the OP, but the fix I suggested fixes the only problem in that code (assuming this code is properly located inside some method).

Comment: ahh got you. Yes he might be having issue somewhere else (above these lines somewhere) and this one he might yet to some up with..

Answer (score 0):

There is no existence of nextString() method in the Scanner class.If the employee's name consists of just a single word,you should use:-
    demoEmpName=keyboard.next();
If the name consists of more than one words,use demoEmpName=keyboard.nextLine();